# Remove elements from an array not containing a certain character

Tags: bash, grep, array

I have an array `c_arr` containing table columns with table aliases. But there are some elements in the array which are actually not columns and so they don't have the format `alias.column_name`.

I need to remove those elements which do not contain a `.`. How can I do that?

The array is created using below statement:

```
c_arr=($echo $(grep -io "\b$alias.\w[a-zA-Z_0-9]*" $output_file))
```

There is another problem with the above line. Even though I am searching for `$alias.` (having a dot after the alias), the array `c_arr` is getting other values too which do not contain a dot.
Sample values of the array are as follows:

```
cab.SYSTEM_NAME
cab.row_id
cab.name
cabxa
cabxa
cab.x_sys_name
cab.status_Cd
cab.LAST_UPD
```

**UPDATE:**

Now, the question at hand is how to remove the elements in the array `c_arr` which does not contain the character `.` if at all the array is having dot and non-dot elements. Contents of `c_arr` is as below:

```
cab.SYSTEM_NAME
cab.row_id
cab.name
cabxa
cabxa
cab.x_sys_name
cab.status_Cd
cab.LAST_UPD
```

The output desired is :

```
cab.SYSTEM_NAME
cab.row_id
cab.name
cab.x_sys_name
cab.status_Cd
cab.LAST_UPD
```

Comment: in regular expressions `.` matches any single character.  To search for a literal `.` you need to escape by preceding with a backslash: `\b$alias\.\w[a-zA-Z_0-9]*`.  Also, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have some data in a file and you want to find some of it to a shell array? What does the original data look like, exactly? And what do you want to do with the contents, exactly?

Comment: When you want to read *lines* into an array, use `mapfile -t c_arr <(grep ...)` and use `declare -p c_arr` to view the contents.

Comment: @BillJetzer Thanks a lot! That solves the original issue and so removing element from the array is not required now. But if at all that was the only case, how could those elements removed (i.e. elements not having a dot)

Comment: what is `$echo` is that an variable you have set?

Answer (score 1):

Then you would probably want to do something like this:

`c_arr=$(echo $(grep -i "${alias}\." $output_file))`

Because as Bill Jetzer mentioned you have to escape the dot in a regular expression.

If you are sure that everything with a dot is valid you could even do:

`c_arr=$(echo $(grep -i \. $output_file))`

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the regular expression operator that matches any single character.

Here, you'd want:

```
readarray -t c_arr < <(LC_ALL=C grep -iPo "\b\Q$alias\E\.\w+")
```

(assuming `$alias` doesn't contain `\E` and your `grep` supports `-P` (it already  supports `-o` which is a GNU extension, so it's likely it will support `-P` as well)).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically answering the question "How to remove elements not containing a certain character from a Bash array".  It's very similar in structure to Stéphane Chazelas' answer.  If you have an array and you want to pare it down, you can do it as illustrated below:

```bsh
$ list=(cab.row_id cab.name cabxa cabxa cab.x_sys_name)
$ printf "%s\n" ${list[@]}
cab.row_id
cab.name
cabxa
cabxa
cab.x_sys_name

$ # vvvv THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION vvvv
$ IFS=$'\n' readarray -t list < <(printf "%s\n" ${list[@]} | grep '\.')
$ # ^^^^ THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION ^^^^

$ printf "%s\n" ${list[@]}
cab.row_id
cab.name
cab.x_sys_name
```

This assumes that no elements contain a `\n` so it can be used as a delimiter.

Somewhat of a tangent:
You can use `unset` to remove specific elements from an array, and that will cause Bash to skip over that element when iterating over the elements, but it will *not* cause all subsequent elements to shift their array index value:

```bsh
$ list=(idx0 idx1 idx2 idx3 idx4)
$ printf "%s\n" ${list[@]}
idx0
idx1
idx2
idx3
idx4

$ unset list[2]
$ printf "%s\n" ${list[@]}
idx0
idx1
idx3
idx4

$ for x in ${list[@]}; do echo $x; done
idx0
idx1
idx3
idx4

$ for i in $(seq 0 4); do echo "$i: ${list[$i]}"; done
0: idx0
1: idx1
2: 
3: idx3
4: idx4
```